# Disable Fabric events for Google's tests

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I see in Google Play Console that Google performs automatically UI tests when I make build to Beta environment.

[image]

It's very nice from their side but there is one problem. Every time those robots open application they click all buttons and in Fabric I see a lot of events from them but not from real users.

In this project we don't have any UI tests configured.

Could someone explain me a solution how to avoid sending events from those tests?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not intended to publish your app frequently to a beta channel.  If you want to run tests frequently and their test data might impact your real data too much, you can create multiple Fabric projects to host different versions of your app, so the test versions don't populate the production version.  When you do this, you should submit your app for testing directly to [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/).